# php, include a local file in a phpfile stored on the server

Tags: php, server, include, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a website that is generated from a server. I have a php file where I include files that are stored on my computer and are necessary for the code to work. The files that I need are related to google calendar API like my credentials and a link to the API folder just like in the quickstart.php example of google (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php).

I think that storing these files on the server is not such a good idea. Is there a way for me to link local files from the server in an include or require? Or do I have to put everything on the server? And in that case how do I know the filepath to my files?

I am not in control of the server I just have acces to a small part of it. It is the school server and I'm working on one directory or so from that server so I can't do anything from root or so.

Thanks in advance and if my question is unclear please notify me so I can rephrase it.

Comment: You will need to put all files on the server. You should not have personal credentials in the files though. Maybe you can create separate credentials (a new google account?) just for this specific purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to protect the code from exposure, try [PHP ionCube Encoder](https://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php). So someone who has access to the server can't read the code, but still it will run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN include remote files via HTTP if you can configure the server to set the following in the php.ini.

```
allow_url_include = On
```

This is NOT the normal setting as it could leave you more vulnerable to attacks. So this method is not a recommended one, but it is possible.

You should consider setting up an additional account on Google and then using that to work with. You can share the relevant calandars from your personal account with that account and thus protect yourself better.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder on your server outside of the public html folder. Go one directory above your website route directory and create your folder there. People will not be able to navigate to that new folder as it is outside of your website route. Store your sensitive files in the new folder. Then just require them in your normal files as needed. This protects your sensitive files in the event your PHP handler failed (rare but can happen) as the content of your sensitive files would not be displayed to people as plain text on your website. Remember to set appropriate folder and file ownership and permissions also on your server.